# Data table column with if else condition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, datatable, datatables

I want to make my one column with if else condition when data table render.
I am using laravel 4.2
my current code is

```
$result = DB::table('flowers')
->select('flowers.id as id', 'flowers.name as name',
'flowers.price as price',
'flowers.description as description','flowers.quality as quality',
'flowers.picture as picture','flowers.visibility_status as visibility_status');

return Datatables::of($result)

->edit_column('visibility_status', '<button type="button" onclick="activeFunction({{ $id }})" class="btn btn-primary bpad">Make Featured</button>')

->edit_column('picture', '<img src="{{ $picture }}" alt="flower Image" height="150">')
->add_column('edit', '<a href="/admin/flower/{{ $id }}"><i class="icon-list-alt"></i>Edit</a>')
->add_column('delete', '<a href="/admin/article_delete/{{ $id }}"><i class="icon-trash"></i>Delete</a>')
->make();
```

i want visibility_status column implement with if else condition like

```
if($visibility_status==1)
{
<div id="active454">
<button type="button" onclick="activeFunction(454)" class="btn btn-primary bpad">Make Featured</button></div>
<div id="block454" style="display:none"><button type="button" onclick="blockFunction(454)" class="btn btn-danger bpad">Make Unfeatured</button></div> 
}
else
{
<div id="active454" style="display:none">
<button type="button" onclick="activeFunction(454)" class="btn btn-primary bpad">Make Featured</button></div>
<div id="block454" ><button type="button" onclick="blockFunction(454)" class="btn btn-danger bpad">Make Unfeatured</button></div> 
}
```

Is it possible

Comment: Can you show your datatables initialisation code?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with laravel but will risk it.

**CSS**

```
.hide{display:none;}
```

**PHP Init**

```
$class1 = array('class="hide" ','');
$class2 = array('','class="hide" ');
```

**In PHP HTML generation**

```
<div id="active454" $class1[$visibility_status]>
<div id="block454"  $class2[$visibility_status]>
```

If `$visibility_status` is ambiguous as far as data type or null use:

```
$classX[intval($visibility_status)]
```